# how to pass a string in laravel route

Tags: php, laravel

$doc has a link. for example

```
$doc = /storage/source/logo.jpg
```

I have a view like this below.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{url('admin/download/take')}}/{{$doc}}">{{$doc}}</a>
```

i have this route below

```
Route::get('download/take/{link})','IncomingController@getGo');
```

and this is my function

```
    public function getGo(Request $request, $link){
    print_r($link);

}
```

the function does not work and laravel route cant accept any string. how do i get the string inside the function

Answer (score 4):

Set name() which alias of your route.

```
 Route::get('download/take/{link})','IncomingController@getGo')->name('download.take.link');
```

change your anchor link as below

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('download.take.link', ['link' => base64_encode($doc)])}}">{{$doc}}</a>
```

Controller function

```
 public function getGo(Request $request, $link){
     $link = base64_decode($link);
     print_r($link); // here you will have link you have passed with URL.
 }
```

Comment: works fine for a string. my links are coming like this. /storage/images/something.jpg...any suggestions how i can get this in function.?

Comment: You are already getting in a function getGo(), as $link. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I also suggest if you pass the link encode format and decode it while getting it in your function.

Comment: works fine if i pass string, but doesnt work if its a link.

Comment: Yeah! that's why, I suggest to encode it. I will edit it in answer.
@AbidusSattarAziz

Comment: i am still getting this below
/admin/download/take/%2Fstorage%2Fsource%2Fmyhunk.jpg%29

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206129/discussion-between-vishal-tarkar-and-abidus-sattar-aziz).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$doc = /storage/source/logo.jpg ;`

```php
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ Storage::url($doc) }}">{{$doc}}</a>
```

if it's not working configure your file system in

`filesystems.php`

```php
 'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

here 
`'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage'`

configure this acording to your need

Comment: works fine for a string. my links are coming like this. /storage/images/something.jpg...any suggestions how i can get this in function.?

Comment: @AbidusSattarAziz make that a single string using " " then may be you can do that

Comment: @KamleshPaul It will cause 404 error if passed string contain link/url or something.

Comment: try Storage::url($doc)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass it as json string in url and then in controller decode it back to url